# CSS Folding animation with transform

Tags: html, css, animation, transform

I have this square: https://jsfiddle.net/34f93mL3/

As you can see, when you hover over it, the top folds down and when it reaches the bottom it becomes a polkadotted pink.

However, what I want to happen is for it to mimic an actual folding motion, meaning it should not have polkadots until it's "folded" a little more.

Here is the full code, which uses only HTML and CSS:

```css
body {
  background: white
}
#slow-container {
  top: 100px;
  left: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
}
#slow-container:before {
  top: -50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
}
#slow-container2 {
  top: -50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
}
.slow-parent1 {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: lightgreen;
}
.slow-parent2 {
  background: white;
}
.slow-parent3 {
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
}
#slow-container2 {
  transition: all 1s linear;
  transform-origin: bottom center;
}
#slow-container:hover #slow-container2 {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  background-color: lightpink;
  background-image: radial-gradient(#fff 10%, transparent 10%), radial-gradient(#fff 10%, transparent 10%);
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  background-position: 0 0, 15px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="slow-container">
  <div id="slow-container2">
  </div>
  <div class="slow-parent1">
    <div class="slow-parent2">
      <div class="slow-parent3">
        stuff goes here later
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove in your hover style code `#fff 10%,` from radial gradient

Comment: yes I did it on my own system, are you want remove pink color also?

Comment: hm, this almost works...it removes the polka dots completely, however. I want it to not show until it's folded a little more, instead of what happens with what I have, which is showing the polkadots on hover. @AnkitGupta

Comment: unable to find what you really want

Comment: I think you want that, dots will appear when we hover, and gets fade with folding and finally will disolve into the solid color right?

Answer (score 1):

Use **CSS3** properties `perspective` to feel folding effect.

References: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/perspective/

```css
body {
  background: white
}
#slow-container {
  top: 100px;
  left: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
}
#slow-container:before {
  top: -50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
}
#slow-container2 {
  top: -50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
}
.slow-parent1 {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: lightgreen;
}
.slow-parent2 {
  background: white;
}
.slow-parent3 {
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
}
#slow-container2 {
  transition: all 1s linear;
  transform-origin: bottom center;
}
#slow-container:hover #slow-container2 {
  transform: perspective(200px) rotateX(180deg);
  background-color: lightpink;
  background-image: radial-gradient(#fff 10%, transparent 10%), radial-gradient(#fff 10%, transparent 10%);
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  background-position: 0 0, 15px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="slow-container">
  <div id="slow-container2">
  </div>
  <div class="slow-parent1">
    <div class="slow-parent2">
      <div class="slow-parent3">
        stuff goes here later
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This definitely helps with the animation portion! Still trying to figure out the polkadots (don't let them show until it folds down more)

Comment: yup, so I think it has something to do with a backface-visibility property? The polka dots are supposed to be the backside of the top piece, so they shouldn't show until the paper is more folded

Comment: @turner that is one of the idea, or you can put delay for applying background image like  https://jsfiddle.net/34f93mL3/4/